# servicestack razor

Tags: servicestack

Does ServiceStack Razor support the full ASP.NET MVC razor syntax? I don't see some of the helper methods like `@Html.DropDownlist...`

If it supports the full syntax, what namespace do I have to include in my Web.config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServiceStack does use a version of Razor from Microsoft, but what you're looking for with `@Html.DropDownList` is an **ASP.NET MVC Html Extension** which have not all been imported into ServiceStack.